# Using Django how can I render in a recursive python function before each return?

Tags: python, django

I am stuck on this. A function runs recursively changing objects each time. I want to render a updated view before every return. How can I render the template on every step of the python function recursive call? Or how can I approach this problem? Here is my function below:

```
def solveBoard(box, board, size):
    if box.isFinalValue:
        newY = box.y
        newX = box.x + 1

        if newX >= size:
            newX = 0
            newY = newY + 1
        if newY >= size:
           return True
        if solveBoard(board[newY][newX], board, size):
            return True
        return False
    else:
        allPossibleValues = getAllPossibleValues(box, board, 9)

        if not allPossibleValues:
            return False
        else:
            for i in allPossibleValues:
                board[box.y][box.x].numValue = i
                board[box.y][box.x].isEmpty = False
                newY = box.y
                newX = box.x + 1

                if newX >= size:
                    newX = 0
                    newY = newY + 1
                if newY >= size:
                    return True

                if solveBoard(board[newY][newX], board, size):
                    return True
                board[box.y][box.x].numValue = 0
                board[box.y][box.x].isEmpty = True
            return False
```

Comment: You probably need to look at some way of running this method asyncronously. You could look into Django channels and use a websocket to stream the data to the client or you could use something like celery and have the client poll the status/results of the task. There are many ways to do this

Comment: @IainShelvington Thank you so much for your help. I relatively new to this so I will google up Django channels. Furthermore, are there any resources with example code that you can recommend?

Comment: The official channels documentation is pretty good https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @IainShelvington  Thanks again.